# Integration test for complex topology (multiple inputs) in Flink

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to write unit test for a flink streaming topology. It's basically a `CoFlatMapFunction`, and it has 2 inputs.

I try to get some inspiration from this page: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html

The order of the inputs matter to my topology, so when I test, I can't use `StreamExecutionEnvironment#fromCollection` for each input, as I won't control the order in which data points are injected in each input.

I've tried to create a single input using `StreamExecutionEnvironment#fromCollection` and dispatch each element to the actual input of my `CoFlatMapFunction` based on their type, but the order of elements is lost in this operation.

Is there another way to write this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flink training exercises have an example of using a TwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness that you can refer to:

https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/test/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_java/process/EventTimeJoinTest.java

You'll need these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-test-utils-junit</artifactId>
  <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${flink.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.19</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-runtime_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${flink.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>
```

You should keep in mind that this isn't a public, supported interface, so it could evolve in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `TwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` class. Unfortunately documentation is a little sparse. I've got a test that uses this class, but it's not yet pushed to the [133_stream-test-harness](https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/flink-crawler/tree/133_stream-test-harness) branch of [flink-crawler](https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/flink-crawler).