# Flink integration testing: Ordering-dependency of input sources

Tags: apache-flink, integration-testing

## What I want to achieve

I want to implement an automated test for a window function in flink which ensures that accumulator and window processing function together create the expected aggregates.

## What I've done so far

I implemented a flink integration test as per the [Flink integration test sample](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/testing/). I instantiated the complete flink application injecting hard-coded sources and a spy for the sink to which the result of the window function is propagated. This works fine, at first glance.

## What's the issue

The test is flaky. Sometimes, it works, sometimes it doesn't.

## Hypothesis

We figured it is probably an issue with the timing with which input sources during the tests are processed.

There are two input streams: `zones` (regional areas with a geometry) and `events` (featuring a coordinate). As part of the flink application, zones are broadcasted and joined (spatially) with the events, so that downstream, all events are assigned to the zones in which they occurred (using a `BroadcastProcessFunction`). Events which don't happen inside the geometry of at least one zone are discarded and are not relevant for the downstream processing, such as the window-operation to be tested.

In the test, we need to make sure that the `zone` stream is processed prior to the events stream. Else, the events-assigned-to-zones may not be created and consequently not aggregated.

## Solution sketches

When thinking about the issue, we thought of three different ways of how to handle the timing-issue:

### Reduce the scope of the integration test

Instead of instantiating the full application, we could set up a simplified version during the integration test which starts with an input source which already features the events-assigned-to-zones. No mulitple input sources => no timing issue. However, this leads to duplication of code which we'd actually like to test. Also, it's nice to have a full end-to-end integration test as in some cases, multiple operators combined deliver value.

### Make one source wait for the other

We tried the `zone` source denote when it's done and have the `event` source wait for that. Usage of `CompletableFuture` is not possible though, as it's (by nature) not serializable.
I had seen [Flink - Integration testing with multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908476/flink-integration-testing-with-multiple-sources) but I was hoping for a more flink-inbuilt alternative (there's a lot of boilerplate-code in the solution).

### Use a savepoint to start from

We though of processing the `zone` stream first (with an empty `event` source), then take a savepoint (in the `@Before` of the test) and then restore from it `@BeforeEach` test. But as far as I've seen I could only restore the full graph from the save point, while when restoring from it, I'd like to swap the `event` source for a source providing a list of dedicated events.

## Help!

It'd be great to get an experienced Flink developer's insights into how to deal with multiple (dependent) sources inside an integration test.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're describing doesn't just exist for your integration test. Imagine that in production, the source of the zone data is delayed (e.g. ops team does maintenance on the Kafka cluster) - you don't want to drop a bunch of initial events, right?

One way to handle this is by buffering in state any events that are candidates to be dropped, with either state TTL or a timer for the max amount of time you're willing to wait.

Then, in the integration test, you set the TTL to some value that is a balance between "long enough to always work" and "don't cause the test to run for too long". Not ideal, but viable.

Or you can do what you mentioned, where you do a "cold-start" of the app, with an empty events source, take a savepoint, and restart from your savepoint in normal mode. Which is functionality that I often bake into the production app, as it removes the need to do buffering.

But it does make the test code significantly more complicated, as you have to start the job async, wait until some indicator (usually a counter) tells you that all broadcast data has been processed, take a savepoint, stop the job, and start it again.

Comment: we're a DevOps-Team, so when doing maintenance on the cluster would include either stopping the Flink application or restarting it with a gapless savepoint lateron ;)
Introducing a buffer for the `events` source would lead to a latency which is always the max amount of time since it's not a single `zone` record we could be waiting for in order to continue. Still, it's a option to introduce the buffer only for testing. Thanks!
Do you have a sample of "savepoint within a test" which you can point to? I didn't find anything on this end.

Comment: Let me poke around for that code...

Answer (score 0):

Since I din't like the idea of adapting my pipeline just for the sake of testability, I followed @till-rohrmanns [solution sketch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54924081/6141374).

Instead of creating a pipeline within the test, we instantiate the full Flink pipeline injecting mocks which then can be asserted.

I documented the overall approach [in a Gist on Github](https://gist.github.com/mrsimpson/7dc9c3f2a15eddb65dd3516dca3f28c6) .

Still, if there are native ways of doing this (or helpers from the `flink-test-utils` which I don't know yet), I'd be most happy to read from experienced devs!

Comment: Thanks for posting the gist - I had a few comments about it.